# Show / Hide children of an li when checkbox is clicked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, hide, show

I have a large unordered list of categories for the user to checkoff what category they want their product to be in. Each Parent category has children. I'd like to hide all the children, and when you check the parent category, the children of the category show. I've tried this code and it toggles all the children elements and not just the one in the current li being checked.

jQuery

```
    $('.wcvendors-pro-dashboard-wrapper ul.product_cat_checklist > li > input[type=checkbox]').change(function()
     {
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $( ".wcvendors-pro-dashboard-wrapper ul.product_cat_checklist li > ul.children" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
      });

      };
    });
```

List

```
<ul class="product_cat_checklist">
    <li id="product_cat-15"><input class="wcv_category_check" value="15" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-15" data-parsley-multiple="product_cat">
    <label class="selectit" for="in-product_cat-15">Home Furnishings</label>
        <ul class="children">
        <li id="product_cat-61">
            <input class="wcv_category_check" value="61" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-61" data-parsley-multiple="product_cat">
            <label class="selectit" for="in-product_cat-61">Bedroom</label>
        </li>
        <li id="product_cat-63">
            <input class="wcv_category_check" value="63" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-63" data-parsley-multiple="product_cat">
            <label class="selectit" for="in-product_cat-63">Children’s Furniture</label>
        </li>
        <li id="product_cat-60">
            <input class="wcv_category_check" value="60" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-60" data-parsley-multiple="product_cat">
            <label class="selectit" for="in-product_cat-60">Kitchen &amp; Dining</label>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li id="product_cat-38">
        <input class="wcv_category_check" value="38" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-38" data-parsley-multiple="product_cat"> 
        <label class="selectit" for="in-product_cat-38">Arts &amp; Crafts</label>
        <ul class="children">
            <li id="product_cat-53">
                <input class="wcv_category_check" value="53" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-53" data-parsley-multiple="product_cat"> 
                <label class="selectit" for="in-product_cat-53">Art Supplies</label>
            </li>
            <li id="product_cat-52">
                <input class="wcv_category_check" value="52" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-52" data-parsley-multiple="product_cat"> 
                <label class="selectit" for="in-product_cat-52">Bath &amp; Beauty</label>
            </li>
            <li id="product_cat-46">
                <input class="wcv_category_check" value="46" type="checkbox" name="product_cat[]" id="in-product_cat-46" data-parsley-multiple="product_cat"> 
                <label class="selectit" for="in-product_cat-46">Clothing &amp; Shoes</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Start with giving the parent/category checkboxes a different class. Currently all checkboxes have same class. Then on change us this to find the children. You are trying to find all children not just the noes inside the checked/unchecked checkbox block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide child `ul`s on page load and show them based on state of checkboxes using following code:

```
$('li > input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    $ul = $this.parent().find('> ul');

  if ($this.is(':checked')) $ul.show();
  else $ul.hide();
});
```

For hiding `ul`s use this `CSS` code:

```
ul.children{
  display: none;
}
```

**[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/mdehghani/bdeumf0h/)**

Comment: This almost works. I just noticed one of my categories has a 3rd level adn the 3rd ul doesn't display when checked. So ul.product_cat_checklist > ul.chidren > ul.chidren
The list is dynamically generated, so adding classes would have to be done with jQuery.

Comment: @JeanLeSheep I just updated my answer and mentioned example (_in example the `Children’s Furniture` item also has sub-items_)